# Boolean argument for script

Tags: python

In Python, I understand how int and str arguments can be added to scripts.

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""Mydescription""")
parser.add_argument('-l', type=str, default='info', help='String argument')
parser.add_argument('-dt', type=int, default ='', help='int argument')
```

What is it for booleans?

Basically I want to pass a flag into my script which will tell the script whether to do a specific action or not.

Comment: What's wrong with `action='store_true'`?

Comment: What behavior do you want with booleans? (say, with '-v true' and '-v false'?)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can either use the `action` with `store_true`|`store_false`, or you can use an int and let implicit casting check a boolean value.

Using the `action`, you wouldn't pass a `--foo=true` and `--foo=false` argument, you would simply include it if it was to be set to true.

```
python myProgram.py --foo
```

In fact I think what you may want is

```
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true', default=False)
```

Comment: I don't believe `default=False` is necessary.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @PaulDraper I've checked that it isn't needed, but you can put it as an explicit value.

Comment: @PaulDraper Isn't the default for boolean True?

Answer (score 20):

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import distutils.util
ARGP.add_argument('--on', '-o', type=distutils.util.strtobool, default='true')
```

Example calling it:

```
$ ./myscript                # argp.on = 1
$ ./myscript --on=false     # argp.on = 0
$ ./myscript --on=False     # argp.on = 0
$ ./myscript --on=0         # argp.on = 0
$ ./myscript --on=1         # argp.on = 1
$ ./myscript -o0            # argp.on = 0
$ ./myscript -o false       # argp.on == 0
```

i should mention, you can bind the argument to a local wrapper function too, to handle some other exact string matching if you want to support values like "yes" and "no". you can also try interpreting the input as yaml, which can handle yes/no too. i haven't done this in a while though, and i think lately I've suck to mutually exclusive arguments with the same `dest` value, one `--no-option` with `action='store_false'`, and one `--option` with `action='store_true'`

Comment: BEST OPTION! -- it allows to put all types of True/False indicators like True/true/1/Y/y/Yes/yes and will return an error if you try to put invalid string like "BlaBlaBla"

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
if __name__=='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--bool_flag', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.bool_flag = bool(eval(args.bool_flag))
    print(args.bool_flag, ',', type(args.bool_flag))
```

For the above python code saved as `tmp.py`:

`python tmp.py --bool_flag '0'` gives `False , <class 'bool'>`

`python tmp.py --bool_flag 'False'` gives `False , <class 'bool'>`

`python tmp.py --bool_flag '1'` gives `True , <class 'bool'>`

`python tmp.py --bool_flag 'True'` gives `True , <class 'bool'>`

Calling above code from a shell script would work too,

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=False
python tmp.py --bool_flag $flag
```

This will give the output: `False , <class 'bool'>`