# Setting a flag using a command-line argument with Argparse4j

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, argparse4j

I am using [argparse4j](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/) to parse command line arguments. I want to add an argument that when present, sets a boolean to true, otherwise it defaults to false. I don't want to include the true or false in the argument, just the identifier, so it would look something like this when run:

```
java firstArg --enable-boolean
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183936/boolean-argument-for-script) shows that in Python, I could set the `action` of the argument to store a true or false value like so:

> ```
> parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true', default=False)
> ```

How can I do the same thing in Java, using argparse4j?

Comment: This is also referred to as a command-line "flag." It helps if you show more code; what you have already got working, which part is not working. I added in example code from the answer you linked, since you want to know how to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Arguments.storeTrue()`](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html#arguments-storetrue-and-arguments-storefalse) action:

> [`Arguments.storeTrue()`](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/argparse4j/impl/Arguments.html#storeTrue()) and [`Arguments.storeFalse()`](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/argparse4j/impl/Arguments.html#storeFalse()) are
>   special cases of [*Arguments.storeConst()*](http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html#arguments-storeconst) using for storing
>   values `true` and `false` respectively. In addition, they create
>   default values of `false` and `true` respectively. For example:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) throws ArgumentParserException {
>     ArgumentParser parser = ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser("prog");
>     parser.addArgument("--foo").action(Arguments.storeTrue());
>     parser.addArgument("--bar").action(Arguments.storeFalse());
>     parser.addArgument("--baz").action(Arguments.storeFalse());
>     System.out.println(parser.parseArgs(args));
> }
> ```
>
> ```bash
> $ java Demo --foo --bar
> Namespace(baz=true, foo=true, bar=false)
> ```